# A button toggle some <li> from a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79k2gbt6/). I have a `ul` list and some `li` inside. I want pressind a button to toggle the 2 first `li`. I tried to put `<li class="s1">` and then

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
      $("ul.s1").click(function() {
            $(this).slideToggle(300);
            return false;
      });
});
```

```html
<button>button</button> 
<ul>
    <li class="s1">1</li>
    <li class="s1">1</li>
    <li>9023698</li>
    <li>8993127</li>
    <li>9037891</li>
</ul>
```

but nothing happens..

Comment: Your browser has a JavaScript error console. Use it: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @Quentin probably because whereever you're testing doesn't have jQuery...

Comment: @DLeh — That error is from the OP's original live example, not my implementation.

Comment: first you need to add jQuery to the jsfiddle, second like @andeersg you need a space between ul and .s1.  and you do know you need to click on button and than click on the first two li for the .s1 to slide right?

Comment: Unrelated: you should normally call `.finish()` or `.stop()` before calling an animation function, else you can spam-click the element and the animations queue up, which can be a bit ugly to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to give the `li` their own click event if you want them to slide on click of the `button`. Secondly, the selector for the `li` elements is incorrect. Thirdly the jsFiddle you setup didn't include jQuery. Try this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("ul .s1").slideToggle(300);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pxk16f31/)

Comment: thx @RoryMcCrossan. If i want to change also the background color of the button

Comment: Add a class to your CSS, and use `addClass()` in jQuery to assign it to the button.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $("ul .s1").slideToggle(300);
  return false;
});
```

A space between ul and class should fix it.

And you don't need the click handler for list element.